# Can't upload wordpress theme, plugins or images with Filezilla

Tags: themes, ftp, plugins, wordpress, upload

I'm using Ubuntu 16.

If I download a plugin in the wordpress panel it works fine, 
but when I upload a plugin, image or theme with FTP (FileZilla) nothing happens.

It does create a directory with files, but Wordpress doesn't do anything with it.
I have multiple websites with the same problem (on the same server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with the permissions.
To see all plugins and themes that are installed in Wordpress you should use the command:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not a Ubuntu question. As, if you have can upload to the FTP server then it is not a permissions issue. So the place this should go is in Stack Overflow or a Wordpress one (if exists).

But you need to activate your theme as follows:

1. Log in to the WordPress Administration Panels.
2. Select the Appearance panel, then Themes.
3. From the Themes panel, roll over the Theme thumbnail image for the
4. Theme you are interested in to see options for that theme.
5. clicking Live Preview to test.
6. To activate the Theme click the Activate button.

More on themes can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes#Selecting_the_Active_Theme)

Comment: It is certainly a Ubuntu question. Why would it be a Wordpress questions if I have the problems on all my websites? Also, I don't want to bypass it by doing it in the dashboard. I want to find a solution for my problem, since I will have to make more websites in the future.

Comment: Have you checked file permissions then?

Comment: You can find more on permissions [here].(https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) . And if you can access the server you can run `ls -la` to see the permission in the directory.

Comment: This is definitely an Ubuntu question. Permissions are set differently for Wordpress (whatever user that is) and FTP. I'd love to know how to make things work for both.

Answer (score 0):

step-1 : First open wp-config.php file of your wordpress installation folder.
step-2: Copy below code and paste it at the end of the wp-config.php file.

define('FS_METHOD','direct');

step-3: Now open your droplet access console and enter root as username and its password.
step-4: Copy below code and paste it into access console where you have to specify your plugin directory path and then hit enter.

chmod 777 /yourwebsitename/public/wp-content/plugins/